# Outputing a list separated by space

Tags: c++, ostream

I'm overloading operator << to output my container separated by space:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const MyContainer &v)
{
    os << "[";
    for (const auto &i : v) {
        os << i << " ";
    }
    os << "\b]"; // <--
    return os;
}

MyContainer c{1,2,3};
std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
```

I'm using '\b' to avoid the extra space at the end of the list, it works fine with above code.

But it might not be a good idea, does '\b' work well with other types of `ostream`? Any other idea to output data like this?

Comment: Compilers should eventually support [`std::experimental::ostream_joiner`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner) (GCC will in version 6), until then you'll have to roll your own solution or use boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it might not be a good idea, does `'\b'` work well with other types of `ostream`?

You are absolutely right about this not being a good idea: `'\b'` works fine in console mode, but it does not play well with other streams, such as files.

A better approach is to not output the extra space in the first place:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const MyContainer &v)
{
    os << "[";
    auto first = true;
    for (const auto &i : v) {
        if (!first) {
            os << " ";
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        os << i;
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: `ostream_iterator` very conspicuously doesn't solve the problem. It's boneheaded.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Oops, you are right, I think I ran into this silly behavior once, but I keep forgetting about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple pragmatic solution is to just add a space before the range loop:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const MyContainer &v)
{
    os << "[ "; // <--
    for (const auto &i : v) {
        os << i << " ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

MyContainer c{1,2,3};
std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
```

The result is a slightly different output, but still achieves the presumed goal of visually pleasing symmetrical formatting: instead of `[1 2 3]` you get `[ 1 2 3 ]`. Empty lists will print as `[ ]`.